# Calculating all possible outcomes for Multinom in R

Tags: r, multinomial

In stats::Multinomial, there is an example of calculating all possible outcomes for Multinom(N=3, K=3):

```
X <- t(as.matrix(expand.grid(0:3, 0:3))); X <- X[, colSums(X) <= 3]
X <- rbind(X, 3:3 - colSums(X)); dimnames(X) <- list(letters[1:3], NULL)
X
round(apply(X, 2, function(x) dmultinom(x, prob = c(1,2,5))), 3)
```

How can I generalize this, i.e. modify the code to easily choose different values for N and K?

Comment: Its slightly unclear what exactly your sampling process is have you looked at `combn` and `choose`?

Comment: This is the example given in the help page of stats::Multinom, all I want is to be able to easily modify the values for N and K in this code.

Comment: As far as i can see `Multinom` is not a help page of `stats` that does not make it easier to understand you question. I now see you mean the help of `dmultinom`

Answer (score 0):

I used this same code from the help page for a class example about chess grandmasters:

Suppose Carlsen and Nakamura are playing a set of 5 classical chess games. What's the probability that, in the next 5 games, Carlsen wins 2, Nakamura wins 1, and they tie twice? Suppose their games are independent and the probabilities follow their historical record, where Carlsen's record against Nakamura is 14W-1L-26T (from chessgames.com as of Jan 3, 2023).

```
# Set size
size <- 5

# Set possible results from chess match
results <- c("C wins", "N wins", "Tie")

X <- t(as.matrix(expand.grid(0:size, 0:size))) 

X <- X[, colSums(X) <= size]

X <- rbind(X, size:size - colSums(X)) 

dimnames(X) <- list(results, NULL)

X

# Calculate probabilities for each possible outcome
round(apply(X, 2, function(x) dmultinom(x, prob = c(14, 1, 26))), 3)
```

To answer your question, I replaced the "3" in your example with "size", which the example above uses as 5.

You don't need to provide a "k", since this code will show you all the possible outcomes (the various values of k) and it will calculate the corresponding probabilities of each. In other words, a multinomial distribution has parameters N and the probabilities (not the values of K).

To make it this code more general, you could define your probabilities (e.g. as probs), then use

```
dmultinom(x, prob = probs)
```

I made two other slight changes to the code you provided:

1. I changed the dimnames to "results" instead of using a, b, c to clarify the result of a given chess match.
2. I separated the lines and added a few comments for clarity.